# Check filename inside a folder contains a pattern using glob()

Tags: php, file, glob, dir

I need to check the files inside a folder contains `'_'` symbol. I have used the glob function to get the files from server location. But I am unaware to check the filenames contains the symbol anywhere within the filename. 
I have files having names like the following format. `student_178_grade1A`

I have done like this.

```
$report_files=glob( '/user_uploads/'  . '/reportcards/' . 'term' . '_' . 10.'/*'.'.pdf' );

//this will return all files inside the folder.

if(count(report_files)>0)
 {
        //some stuff
 }
 else
 {

 }
```

I need to get the files which has '_' within the filename.I tried

```
glob( '/user_uploads/'  . '/reportcards/' . 'term' . '_' . 10.'/*[_]'.'.pdf' );
```

but its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression doesn't seem correct. This might do what you want:

```
// Find any file in the directory "/user_uploads/reportcards/term_10/" 
// that has the file extension ".pdf"
$report_files = glob("\/user_uploads\/reportcards\/term\_10\/(.*)\.pdf");

// Find any file in the directory "/user_uploads/reportcards/term_10/" 
// containing the character "_".
$report_files = glob("\/user_uploads\/reportcards\/term\_10\/(.*)\_(.*)");

// Find any file in the directory "/user_uploads/reportcards/term_10/" 
// that has the file extension ".pdf" and contains the "_" character
$report_files = glob("\/user_uploads\/reportcards\/term\_10\/(.*)\_(.*)\.pdf");
```

If you don't understand exactly what the regular expression does, I made a quick summary of what is being done down below. There's also a great website to try out regular expresison with documentation on how to construct them [here](http://www.regexr.com/).

```
\/ = escapes the / character
\_ = escapes the _ character
\. = escapes the . character
(.*) = matches any character, number etc
```

Comment: I have used
 $report_files = glob("\/user_uploads\/reportcards\/term\_10'.'/*'.'_*\.pdf'");
//this works for me.  Thanks for giving me the idea.

Answer (score 1):

First off you forgot a quotation mark after term.

```
$report_files = glob('/user_uploads/'.'/reportcards/'.'term'.'_'.10.'/*[_]'.'.pdf');
```

Secondly you have two slashes after `user_uploads`.

```
$report_files = glob('/user_uploads/reportcards/'.'term'.'_'.10.'/*[_]'.'.pdf');
```

Comment: I have forgotten to add the quatation mark for term  in the question.

Comment: I need to filter the filenames which contains underscore in it.